# How to loop json format array variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, google-maps

This is my code, using for marking all places that I fetched from my database in google map.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/church_finder/index.php/MapController/search_church",
                type:'POST',
                data:{coordinates:coordinates}
                 success: receiver               
               });
```

Here I call the function receiver with the result I got from the database.

```
function receiver(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

var json = JSON.parse(data);

var features = [
            for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
            var lat=json[0]["lat"];
            var lng=json[0]["lng"];
                {
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                },
            }
            ];

     features.forEach(function(feature) {
                var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: feature.position,
                    map: map
                });
            });     
}
```

This is the result data I getting from ajax

> [{"lat":"10.526800731337735","lng":"76.20941162109375"},
>   {"lat":"10.622100079463674","lng":"76.1424207687378"},{"lat":"10.604004340704408","lng":"76.14100456237793"},{"lat":"10.608644375798574","lng":"76.13735675811768"},{"lat":"10.624419968495433","lng":"76.13675594329834"},{"lat":"10.62436724394038","lng":"76.13685250282288"},{"lat":"10.624377788852131","lng":"76.13693833351135"},{"lat":"10.615815200680679","lng":"76.1367130279541"},{"lat":"10.601726479547619","lng":"76.13688468933105"},{"lat":"10.610500370131295","lng":"76.13244295120239"},{"lat":"10.631991120088175","lng":"76.13566160202026"}]

but when am using forloop inside var feature I got error like this "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for". How can i loop and mark all this coordinate in google map.

Comment: You can't put a for loop inside an array like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is your approach

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);

var features = [
    for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
    var lat=json[0]["lat"];
    var lng=json[0]["lng"];
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        },
    }
    ];

features.forEach(function(feature) {
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            map: map
        });
    });     
}
```

## There are some issues in your code

You're trying to execute a `for-loop` within both brackets `[]`

```
var features = [  
    for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++) { <- Here
    var lat=json[0]["lat"];
    var lng=json[0]["lng"];
        {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        },
    }
    ];
    ^
```

You're always itetaring with position `0`

```
var lat=json[0]["lat"];
var lng=json[0]["lng"];
             ^
```

You have an expression that never was assigned to a variable:

```
{
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
},
^
```

## Look this code snippet with those fixes

```
var json = [{"lat":"10.526800731337735","lng":"76.20941162109375"}, {"lat":"10.622100079463674","lng":"76.1424207687378"},{"lat":"10.604004340704408","lng":"76.14100456237793"},{"lat":"10.608644375798574","lng":"76.13735675811768"},{"lat":"10.624419968495433","lng":"76.13675594329834"},{"lat":"10.62436724394038","lng":"76.13685250282288"},{"lat":"10.624377788852131","lng":"76.13693833351135"},{"lat":"10.615815200680679","lng":"76.1367130279541"},{"lat":"10.601726479547619","lng":"76.13688468933105"},{"lat":"10.610500370131295","lng":"76.13244295120239"},{"lat":"10.631991120088175","lng":"76.13566160202026"}];

var features = [];

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  var lat = json[i]["lat"];
  var lng = json[i]["lng"]; 

  features.push({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
  });
}

features.forEach(function(feature) {
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: feature.position,
    map: map
  });
});
```

## Resources

- [Loops and iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Comment: I missed this the first go around as well, but `json[0]` should be `json[i]`

Comment: Good explanation of the issue. +1'd

Comment: @Ele Thank you so much it's working fine. Sorry that's my mistake i forgot to change, before i put 0 without for loop to check it's working or not. Any way Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

You can't put the `for` keyword inside of an array, as you are trying to do in `features = [ for (...) {} ]`. Try this instead:

```
function receiver(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {

  var json = JSON.parse(data);

  var features = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var lat = json[i]["lat"];
    var lng = json[i]["lng"]; 
    // push object into features array
    features.push({ position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng) });
  }

  features.forEach(function(feature) {
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: feature.position,
      map: map
    });
  });
}
```

Or, to make it more concise, you can use [ES6 Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) with [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), like so:

```
var features = json.map(({lat, lng}) => ({position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)}));
```