# How to add google maps marker from array (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, google-maps

I hope for a bit support about my following javascript code:

```js
// Initialize Firebase
var config = { 
    apiKey           : "AIzaSyBRC2kza6jhghEFNr5dteVpw2kB9mxqrU8",
    authDomain       : "formulaire-7fba1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL      : "https://formulaire-7fba1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId        : "formulaire-7fba1",
    storageBucket    : "formulaire-7fba1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "548100244430"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0},
        zoom: 3,
        styles: [{
            featureType: 'poi',
            stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] // Turn off points of interest.
        }, {
            featureType: 'transit.station',
            stylers: [{ visibility: 'off' }] // Turn off bus stations, train stations, etc.
        }],
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    });
}

// Loop through users in order with the forEach() method. The callback
// provided to forEach() will be called synchronously with a DataSnapshot
// for each child:
var query = firebase.database().ref("client").orderByKey();
query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    var position = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        // key will be "ada" the first time and "alan" the second time
        var key = childSnapshot.key;

        // childData will be the actual contents of the child
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        position.push(childData.lat + " " + childData.lng);
        console.log(position);
    });
});
```

I'm trying to get the array, that's filled with GPS position as a strings, into the google map, as markers. Tried several methods but none works. Can anyone can give me a tip or an direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If `position` is the array that will hold your coordinates. You need to make sure the array elements inside follow a `latLng` object or what the `marker.position` property would recognize. Usually it would follow this format:

`var latLngObj = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};`

You can use your `forEach` loop to already add a marker per iteration. Before/Aftter pushing the coordinates to the `position` array do something like:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: {lat: childData.lat, lng:childData.lng},
          map: map
        });
```

I'm not sure how childData actually looks like, as you didn't give that info, but assuming it's a `double` like -25.363 and not a `string`, then it will be fine.

You might also want to define your map variable globally so that your functions can recognize it at the part of `map: map` as you're only defining the `map` variable inside your `initMap` function.

Here's the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map) that may guide you on how to add a marker to the map. Just use an iteration (e.g. for loop) to add multiple markers. You'll also see how to delete them in the same [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#remove).

Also found a relevant [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567601/how-to-loop-json-format-array-variable-in-javascript) on properly looping to create your markers.

Hope that helps!